# Bounty for attention (though it's a good question)

Tags: support, questions, bounty

Ok, Guys. Recently, I poked into this question: [James Webb Space Telescope's halo orbit at Lagrange point L2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41814/) asked by @Michael which is *pretty good*. As it didn't get enough attention, I started a bounty on it. Seems like it doesn't get attention now either. I don't think, these *Physics guys* are bored of seeing such a question. At the same time, we shouldn't expect equal interests from others. But, Is there any other reason for this question - *not getting  attention*..?

*(I think It'd get attention at least in meta :-)*

Answer (score 7):

This Q is +10 so it got quite a lot of attention and appreciation -- the fact that it has no answers is more connected to the fact it is a pretty tough question.

Comment: It got a lot of attention only after throwing a bounty. Ok, Thanks mbq

Comment: It is a tough question in the sense that a run of the mill physicist will have to brush off a lot of kinematics and gravitational equations to answer it. I do not answer questions that would take me 8 hours to do so ( that is how much time I spent the first time i had to   prepare a graduate course classical mechanics lecture). It is only in the field people work in directly that an answer will be extracted so it is evident that no astrophysicist involved in the project follows this board.

Comment: Yeah, the best thing to do with that would be to share links to it and try to attract someone who can answer it.